# How to create a cross-reference to a section in the appendix?

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref, appendix

I want to cross-reference an appendix in my LaTeX document. The appendix is defined as follows:

```
\usepackage{cleveref}
\appendix
\section{title1}
\label{label1}
\section{title2}
\label{label2}
How to refer to \cref{label1}
```

and the output is:

```
Appendix A. title1
Appendix B. title2
How to refer to Appendix Appendix A
```

In the output, I don't know why the word "Appendix" appears twice. How to have "Appendix" appear only once? I appreciate any help.

Edit:
Based on the comments, I am providing a more complete code below. Pasting it into a blank project on Overleaf will give you the duplicated "Appendix" I mentioned above.

```
\documentclass[review,twocolumn,sort&compress]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\appendix
\section{title1}
\label{label1}
\section{title2}
\label{label2}

How to refer to \cref{label1}

\end{document}
```

Comment: As always on the site, please provide a full but minimal example that others can copy and test as is. People tend to ignore questions like this.

Comment: We haven't any idea, how you refer your appendix. Please consider @daleif coment!

Comment: @Jen Have you tried `\ref` instead of `\cref`?

Comment: @ojdo No I have not, and \ref works. Apparently I was complicating things. Problem solve, thanks!